# Unable to create thread pipe: Too many open files on CasperJS

Tags: javascript, error-handling, phantomjs, casperjs

I have make a CasperJS script to grab all the images from many links. When I run it, it works for several minutes and after it throws me this error.

And I don't know how to solve this problem.

My CasperJS script:

```
casper.repeat(200, function() {
    casper.thenOpen('http://google.fr/', function() { // Get a new page
        res = this.evaluate(function(wsurl) {
            return JSON.parse(__utils__.sendAJAX(wsurl, 'POST', null, false));
        }, {wsurl: ajax_url});
    });
    casper.then(function(){
        this.wait(1000);
    })
    casper.then(function(){
        this.open(res.source); // Open it
    });
    casper.then(function(){
        this.wait(1000);
    });
    casper.then(function(){
        arr_img = this.getElementsAttribute('img', 'src');
    });
    casper.then(function(){
        arr_img.forEach(function(value, key){ // Grab the images
            var img = new Image();
            img.src = value;
            if(img.width >= 337){
                temp  = {};
                temp['image']  = value;
                temp['width']  = img.width;
                temp['height'] = img.height;
                arr.push(temp);
            }
            delete window.img;
        });
    });
    casper.then(function(){
        require('utils').dump(arr);
        // Save the array
    });
    casper.then(function(){
        this.clear();
    });
});
```

My error:

```
QEventDispatcherUNIXPrivate(): Unable to create thread pipe: Too many open files
2014-09-20T15:37:27 [FATAL] QEventDispatcherUNIXPrivate(): Can not continue without a  thread pipe
Abort trap: 6
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [PhantomJS using too many threads](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15005830/phantomjs-using-too-many-threads) (first result when googling for `phantomjs QEventDispatcherUNIXPrivate`)